# dyld`__abort_with_payload error and Thread 1 signal SIGABRT when running app on my iPad but runs fine on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, error-handling, swiftui

I' m working on a project in Xcode. I'm using SwiftUI and Swift to build it. Everything works fine in the simulator, nothing to worry about. When I try to run the app on my iPad it still builds everything but it shows black screen on the iPad and gives me errors on the debug navigator. I have searched everywhere but I can't find a solution. Please help me 
The errors:

```
    dyld__abort_with_payload:
    0x1028875dc <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
    0x1028875e0 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x1028875e4 <+8>:  b.lo   0x102887600               ; <+36>
    0x1028875e8 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x1028875ec <+16>: mov    x29, sp
    0x1028875f0 <+20>: bl     0x102885be8               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1028875f4 <+24>: mov    sp, x29
    0x1028875f8 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
    0x1028875fc <+32>: ret    
    0x102887600 <+36>: ret 

dyld_dyld_start:
    0x10283d000 <+0>:   mov    x28, sp
    0x10283d004 <+4>:   and    sp, x28, #0xfffffffffffffff0
    0x10283d008 <+8>:   mov    x0, #0x0
    0x10283d00c <+12>:  mov    x1, #0x0
    0x10283d010 <+16>:  stp    x1, x0, [sp, #-0x10]!
    0x10283d014 <+20>:  mov    x29, sp
    0x10283d018 <+24>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x10             ; =0x10 
    0x10283d01c <+28>:  ldr    x0, [x28]
    0x10283d020 <+32>:  ldr    x1, [x28, #0x8]
    0x10283d024 <+36>:  add    x2, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
    0x10283d028 <+40>:  adrp   x3, -1
    0x10283d02c <+44>:  add    x3, x3, #0x0              ; =0x0 
    0x10283d030 <+48>:  mov    x4, sp
    0x10283d034 <+52>:  bl     0x10283d07c               ; 
dyldbootstrap::start(dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, int, char const**, dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, unsigned long*)
->  0x10283d038 <+56>:  mov    x16, x0
    0x10283d03c <+60>:  ldr    x1, [sp]
    0x10283d040 <+64>:  cmp    x1, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
    0x10283d044 <+68>:  b.ne   0x10283d050               ; <+80>
    0x10283d048 <+72>:  add    sp, x28, #0x8             ; =0x8 
    0x10283d04c <+76>:  br     x16
    0x10283d050 <+80>:  mov    x30, x1
    0x10283d054 <+84>:  ldr    x0, [x28, #0x8]
    0x10283d058 <+88>:  add    x1, x28, #0x10            ; =0x10 
    0x10283d05c <+92>:  add    x2, x1, x0, lsl #3
    0x10283d060 <+96>:  add    x2, x2, #0x8              ; =0x8 
    0x10283d064 <+100>: mov    x3, x2
    0x10283d068 <+104>: ldr    x4, [x3]
    0x10283d06c <+108>: add    x3, x3, #0x8              ; =0x8 
    0x10283d070 <+112>: cmp    x4, #0x0                  ; =0x0 
    0x10283d074 <+116>: b.ne   0x10283d068               ; <+104>
    0x10283d078 <+120>: br     x16
```

exception message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/04C7A4C1-585D-418C-8AF9-904E57E5C4DD/TimeManagerApp.app/TimeManagerApp
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/04C7A4C1-585D-418C-8AF9-904E57E5C4DD/TimeManagerApp.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/04C7A4C1-585D-418C-8AF9-904E57E5C4DD/TimeManagerApp.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/04C7A4C1-585D-418C-8AF9-904E57E5C4DD/TimeManagerApp.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=25
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/04C7A4C1-585D-418C-8AF9-904E57E5C4DD/TimeManagerApp.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/04C7A4C1-585D-418C-8AF9-904E57E5C4DD/TimeManagerApp.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/04C7A4C1-585D-418C-8AF9-904E57E5C4DD/TimeManagerApp.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/04C7A4C1-585D-418C-8AF9-904E57E5C4DD/TimeManagerApp.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/04C7A4C1-585D-418C-8AF9-904E57E5C4DD/TimeManagerApp.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'

    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/04C7A4C1-585D-418C-8AF9-904E57E5C4DD/TimeManagerApp.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

Comment: Do you have a free apple developer account?  If so, are you using embedded frameworks and iOS 13.3.1?  Can you add the exception message to your question.

Comment: Yes I'm using a free developer account. I have Pods_APPNAME.framework as embed and sign and the app is for iOS 13.2+ and on my iPad I have iOS 13.3.1.Now I add the exception message. Thanks